# 2D times 2D equals a 3d pytorch tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, matrix-multiplication

Given two 2-D pytorch tensors:

```py
A = torch.FloatTensor([[1,2],[3,4]])
B = torch.FloatTensor([[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]])
```

Is there an efficient way to calculate a tensor of shape (6, 2, 2) where each entry is a column of `A` times each row of `B`?

For example, with A and B above, the 3D tensor should have the following matrices:

```py
[[[0, 0],
  [0, 0]],

 [[1, 1],
  [3, 3]],

 [[2, 2],
  [6, 6]],

 [[0, 0],
  [0, 0]],

 [[2, 2],
  [4, 4]],

 [[4, 4],
  [8, 8]]]
```

I know how to do it via for-loop but I am wondering if could have an efficient way to save it.

Comment: Do you mean matrix multiplication or broadcasted element-wise multiplication? Both give the same results when the rows and columns of A and B are length 2.

Answer (score 1):

Pytorch tensors implement [numpy style broadcast semantics](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) which will work for this problem.

It's not clear from the question if you want to perform *matrix multiplication* or *element-wise multiplication*. In the length 2 case that you showed the two are equivalent, but this is certainly not true for higher dimensionality! Thankfully the code is almost the same so I'll just give both options.

```py
A = torch.FloatTensor([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
B = torch.FloatTensor([[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]])

# matrix multiplication
C_mm = (A.T[:, None, :, None] @ B[None, :, None, :]).flatten(0, 1)

# element-wise multiplication
C_ew = (A.T[:, None, :, None] * B[None, :, None, :]).flatten(0, 1)
```

**Code description.** `A.T` transposes `A` and the indexing with `None` inserts unitary dimensions so `A.T[:, None, :, None]` will be shape `(2, 1, 2, 1)` and `B[None, :, None, :]` is shape `(1, 3, 1, 2)`. Since `@` (matrix multiplication) operates on the last two dimensions of tensors, and broadcasts the other dimensions, then the result is matrix multiplication for each column of `A` times each row of `B`. In the element-wise case the broadcasting is performed on every dimension. The result is a `(2, 3, 2, 2)` tensor. To turn it into a `(6, 2, 2)` tensor we just flatten the first two dimensions using [`Tensor.flatten`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.flatten.html#torch.flatten).

Comment: Thank you. This solves part of my big problem.